# error on magento 2 after update php 5 to 7, Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/registration.php):?

Tags: magento2, error, fatal-error

Error on Magento 2 after update from PHP 5 to PHP 7:

> Warning: require(/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/registration.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 60
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/registration.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/var/www/html/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 60

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I am facing sem issue I have resolved this by below steps

1. Remove below folders

> rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/session/* var/di*
> var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/* generated/code/

2. Update composer

> composer install

3. Setup upgrade

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

4. Content Deploy

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 0):

yes got it, we need to update composer.. i hope it will help some one

Comment: I do not agree that this is not an answer to the question, it is, but it is a bit short... Could you elaborate more? What was the cause and why is this the right solution? What commands did you run?

Comment: i used  rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/session/* var/di* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/* var/generation.

Comment: But you said you had updated composer - now you are saying you deleted the cache folders? @Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/session/* var/di* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/* var/generation

remove Module which you installed recently view composer 
composer remove [companyname]/[modulename]

Remember composer update will update all modules installed via composer

Setup upgrade
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Content Deploy
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
it will work perfect

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was just missing credentials for that package in my auth.json